# Space Characters in Cognito Password

Tags: amazon-cognito

We are currently seeing `InvalidParameterException` when attempting to create users with space characters in their password.

Is there any way to update the password policy to enable this, is it a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Spaces now seem to be supported.
From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html:

> Special character from the following set. The space character is also treated as a special character.

Leading or trailing whitespace does not seem to be supported though - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/869#issuecomment-524921236 is currently the only reference I can find to this limitation, but I have experienced the following a couple of times:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidPasswordException Password does not conform to policy: Password must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^\S.*\S$ (Service: CognitoIdentityProvider, Status Code: 400, Request ID: uuid, Extended Request ID: null)
```

This seems to be a pre-check by Cognito before checking against the configured password policy.

Answer (score 1):

The password policy of Cognito is described in the userPool settings here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html

Currently, Cognito does not support space characters in the password. 
This is not a bug, but the expected behavior right now.

We will consider this request for future releases

Comment: Ouch. That is a pretty tough limitation, meaning you can't really type pass-phrases. They might not be perfect, but many expect to be able to use them.